# Is Angular JS based hybrid app support windows?

Tags: angularjs, windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, ionic-framework

I am working on **cordova based cross platform mobile App** project which needs to be done using **MVC Based framework** and able to work on each windows device like windows phones & tablets. So i selected **Angular + ionic + cordova**.

I tried so many examples to test that **windows platform will work with Angular JS or not** and every time I install app on windows device, **application** was **crashed** each and every time. Those apps are working perfectly on android and ios devices.

I have gone through so many tutorials and blogs for this question, but I didn't find any satisfactory answer. Is there anyway to achieve windows support in angular + ionic?

I tried using "shim" way and also created project through visual studio, but still result is same.

Is there anyone can help me to find answer?

Thanks for help.

Comment: According to a statement of ionic "Windows Phone and FirefoxOS support is on our roadmap. " (Source: http://ionicframework.com/docs/overview/#browser-support) you have to wait until it is supported.

Comment: @Blauharley -What about angular js ??

Comment: I've never made an app based on angular only but you could definetly give it a try because in comparison with ionic it is more lightweighted, does not come with ui-templates and so  it's more likely that it works in all platforms.